# appbar windows phone 8 mvvm

Tags: mvvm-light, windows-phone-8, mvvm-toolkit

Well then , I got something like this in my manipange.xaml , my application bar declaration, and my button declaration/definition

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar x:Name="xxxx" IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton
                x:Name="appBarRegisterButton"
                IconUri="/Images/next.png"
                Text="Login"
                Click="appBarRegisterButton_Click_1" IsEnabled="True"/>
            </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

when i try to change some property from some other model,  fe.
this is my registartion Model.

```
   public RegisterViewModel()
    {
        RegisterTitle = Resources.AppResources.RegisterTitle;
        Messenger.Default.Register<RegisterButtonPressed>(this, msg => AttemptToRegister(msg.reg));
    }


    private void AttemptToRegister(Register reg)
    {
        reg.appBarRegisterButton.IsEnabled = true;
     }
```

It does not change,better my register button is a null object, anyone got a point how to solve this?  ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the button like this:

```
var applicationBarIconButton = ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton;
if (applicationBarIconButton != null)
      {
//do stuff
}
```

The index depending on where it is located in the appbar.